# Decide whether contour is mostly filled or not

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image like this: [image]

I am able to extract all the letters based on solidity, height and aspect ratio, but this also includes the leftmost square. I want to be able to find out if a contour (as this image is already horizontally stacked of multiple letters (and a box)) is mostly filled - white, or not.

I used this code to get the first image from this input image: [image]

```
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np
import cv2


plate_img = cv2.imread('bla1.png')    
V = cv2.split(cv2.cvtColor(plate_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))[2]
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(V, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 6)
labels = measure.label(thresh, connectivity = 2, background = 0)
charCandidates = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

characters = []
for label in np.unique(labels):
  # if this is the background label, ignore it
  if label == 0:
    continue
  # otherwise, construct the label mask to display
  # only connected components for the current label,
  # then find contours in the label mask
  labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
  labelMask[labels == label] = 255

  cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(labelMask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  if len(cnts) > 0:
    # grab the largest contour which corresponds
    # to the component in the mask, then grab the
    # bounding box for the contour
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    (boxX, boxY, boxW, boxH) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # compute the aspect ratio, solodity, and
    # height ration for the component
    aspectRatio = boxW / float(boxH)
    solidity = cv2.contourArea(c) / float(boxW * boxH)
    heightRatio = boxH / float(plate_img.shape[0])

    # determine if the aspect ratio, solidity,
    # and height of the contour pass the rules tests
    keepAspectRatio = aspectRatio < 1.05
    keepSolidity = 0.15 < solidity < 0.875
    keepHeight = heightRatio > 0.5 and heightRatio < 0.95

    # check to see if the component passes all the tests
    if keepAspectRatio and keepSolidity and keepHeight and boxW >= 6:
      # compute the convex hull of the contour
      # and draw it on the character candidates mask
      hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
      cv2.drawContours(charCandidates, [hull], -1, 255, -1)

contours = cv2.findContours(charCandidates, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
for c in contours:
  (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
  temp = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
  characters.append(temp)
      
return characters
```

Comment: What is `bgr_thresh`? I would think you could just take a mean of the pixel data there and set a threshold for rejection...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace it. It was meant to be `thresh`.

Comment: So can you look at the mean value of temp to inform you of the whiteness?

Comment: Indeed I can, thank you, I will try some experiments now.